Запуск исполняемой функции из расширения через фразу-идентификатор в начале php скрипта
Есть ли какой-то вариант чтобы на этапе анализа Зендом файла с расширением php автоматически при детекте какой-то фразы (например после <?php написать @STARTWORK) - сразу стартовало написанное мною расширение, которому бы передавалось все остальное содержимое файла? Знаю что в Zend используется "метка" формата :
<?php @Zend

Но нигде нет исходников, чтобы понять каким образом отслеживается эта метка на этапе запуска файла php и дальнейшая работа с зашифрованной частью файла.
По идее сначала надо выполнить zend_parse_parameters, потом каким-то образом получить остаток файла, из которого эта метка и прилетела, после чего уже выполнить zend_eval_string для готового кода. Но вот как инициализировать работу расширения без явного вызова функции в начале файла и как получить само содержимое скрипта, из которого, собственно, и вызывается расширение-то?

Чтобы расширение стартовало необходима директива в конфиге php или аргумент командной строки. А уж потом разбирайте в расширении содержимое файла и определяйте наличие каких-то идентификаторов и предпринимайте какие-то действия.

@user7860670 вы имеете ввиду что надо объявить расширение через 'extension = '? Это ведь и так понятно, как и то что компилировать надо под конкретную версию php. Или речь идет про какой-то другой конфиг?

Да, про zend_extension и extension. Ну а если это понятно, то непонятна суть вопроса, расширение же будет стартавоть.

@user7860670 речь идет про инициализацию расширения с его последующей отработкой по файлу, в котором была замечена инициализация. Нужно чтобы расширение стартовало не от вызова функции, а при моменте когда в файле замечается нейкая последовательность символов, кодовая, после чего весь остаток файла php скрипта передается этому расширению и уже оно его кидает в интерпретатор через zend_eval_string, предварительно внеся все нужные изменения в код.

Инициализация расширения происходит при его загрузке в php, до интерпретации файлов. Как я понимаю, этот вопрос все же не про инициализацию, а про установку хука перед интерпретацией файла.

@user7860670 ммм, да, пожалуй вы правы. Поправил название, чтобы было более понятно о чем речь.
